# Setting body text of mailto from asp.net code behind method

Tags: asp.net, mailto

I have an ASP.NET button. If the user clicks this button, then it calls `mailto`, which opens the outlook mail window. I have done this by adding the following line into the ASP.net button control tag.

`window.open('mailto: abc def<abc.def@ex.com>?subject= exSub &body= exBody');`

Now I want to set the body text (in the above example it is exBody) dynamically in my code behind method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind it to a page property, and use the property to construct the *mailto* attribute ([URL-encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368)):

```
<asp:Button RunAt = "Server"
    onclick = <%# 
        "window.open('mailto: abc def<abc.def@ex.com>?subject= exSub &body="
        + Server.UrlEncode(MailToBody ?? "") + "');"
    %>
/>
```

Then set the `MailToBody` property from your code-behind as needed.

Comment: Isn't it `OnClientClick`? I tired it, but it's not working. I am using ASP.NET 3.5. If I don't use `<%# %>`, then new outlook window opens but I cannot set the body text dynamically. If I use `<%# %>` nothing happens.

Comment: @HelloWorld try using `<%=` instead.  (`<%#` requires the databinding to be set up correctly.)

Comment: It doesn't compile, shows an error message. Just letting you know that I have this button (ans script) inside the update panel. Is the reason that it's not working?

Comment: @HelloWorld ah, sorry, didn't realize you can't use `<%=` in server tags.  I don't think the update panel should matter.

Comment: @HelloWorld I just tested it, and `OnClientClick` isn't working for me either.  I suggest using `onclick` instead, I was able to get that working as in my answer.  Just make sure the page is data-bound (eg, by using `this.DataBind()` in `Page_Load`).

Comment: Now it works. Thanks for your help. I am selecting this solution as my accepted answer. However, the other solution given by LolCoder also works.

Answer (score 5):

You can register script in `Click` event of button in codebehind following way:

```
 string mailBody = getMailBody(); //// Get the content for email body
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mailto",
        "window.open('mailto: abc def<abc.def@ex.com>?subject= exSub &body= "+ mailBody +"');", true);
```

Comment: If the button is inside the `Update Panel`, `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` doesn't work. However, `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` works. Thanks for your help.